# I have a problem in use sidenav menu with mini variant

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create mini variant but have a problem in it.

I was created mini variant sidenav menu. I created button in my list menu in "sidenav-listcomponent" but now I want to use button action in my "menu button" on "headercomponent"

My "headercomponent" code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { SidenavListComponent } from '../sidenav-list/sidenav-list.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
@Directive({
  selector:'app-sidenav-list'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(SidenavListComponent) child:SidenavListComponent;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  Onclick(){
    this.child.onSinenavToggle();
  }
}
```

my headercomponent html code is:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z6">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)=" Onclick()">
                <mat-icon  *ngIf="sideNavState || !sideNavState">menu</mat-icon>               
            </button>
     </span> 
     <span>
        <img src="assets/images/okcs-logo.png" alt="افق کوروش" width="70" />
    </span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and my "sidenavlistcomponent" angular code is:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidenavService } from '../menuservices/sidenav.service';
import { onSideNavChange, animateText } from '../menuanimation/animations';

interface Page {
  link: string;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav-list',
  templateUrl: './sidenav-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav-list.component.scss'],
  animations: [onSideNavChange, animateText]
})
export class SidenavListComponent implements OnInit {

  public sideNavState: boolean = false;
  public linkText: boolean = false;

  public pages: Page[] = [
    {name: 'Inbox', link:'some-link', icon: 'inbox'},
    {name: 'Starred', link:'some-link', icon: 'star'},
    {name: 'Send email', link:'some-link', icon: 'send'},
  ]
  constructor(private _sidenavService: SidenavService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSinenavToggle() {
    this.sideNavState = !this.sideNavState

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.linkText = this.sideNavState;
    }, 200)
    this._sidenavService.sideNavState$.next(this.sideNavState)
  }
}
```

and my "sidenavlistcomponent" html code is:

```html
<div class="sidenav_container"  [@onSideNavChange]="sideNavState ? 'open' : 'close'">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height: 100%;">

    <div class="user_menu">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item>
          <img class="jim" src="https://a57.foxnews.com/media2.foxnews.com/BrightCove/694940094001/2018/06/21/931/524/694940094001_5800293009001_5800284148001-vs.jpg?ve=1&tl=1" alt="">
          <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>

    <div>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
          <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <span [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onSinenavToggle()">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="sideNavState || !sideNavState" >arrow_left</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

my "appcomponent" typescript code is:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SidenavService } from './components/global/menuservices/sidenav.service';
import { onMainContentChange } from './components/global/menuanimation/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [ onMainContentChange ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  public onSideNavChange: boolean;

  constructor(private _sidenavService: SidenavService) {
    this._sidenavService.sideNavState$.subscribe( res => {
      this.onSideNavChange = res;
    })
  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

my "appcomponent" html code is:

```html
<app-header></app-header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/okcs-logo.png" alt="افق کوروش" width="70" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#headerNavbarCollapse"
        aria-controls="headerNavbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="headerNavbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a routerLink="/applications" class="nav-link">صفحه اصلی</a>
          </li>
          <li class="pl-3" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a routerLink="/application/create" class="btn btn-danger" routerLinkActive="active">
              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
              ایجاد برنامه جدید
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input type="text" value="" placeholder="جستجو در برنامه‌ها..." class="form-control" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header> -->

    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
        <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
            <app-sidenav-list></app-sidenav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content [@onMainContentChange]="onSideNavChange ? 'open': 'close'">
          <div class="main_content">
            <div style="padding: 20px">
                <div class="container" id="app">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
      </mat-sidenav-container>

<footer></footer>
```

and my "sidenavservice" code is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SidenavService {

  public sideNavState$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  constructor() { }
}
```

my animation typescript code:

```js
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, animateChild, query } from '@angular/animations';


export const onSideNavChange = trigger('onSideNavChange', [
  state('close',
    style({
      'min-width': '50px',

    })
  ),
  state('open',
    style({
      'min-width': '200px',
    })
  ),
  transition('close => open', animate('250ms ease-in')),
  transition('open => close', animate('250ms ease-in')),
]);


export const onMainContentChange = trigger('onMainContentChange', [
  state('close',
    style({
      'margin-left': '62px'
    })
  ),
  state('open',
    style({
      'margin-right': '200px'
    })
  ),
  transition('close => open', animate('250ms ease-in')),
  transition('open => close', animate('250ms ease-in')),
]);


export const animateText = trigger('animateText', [
  state('hide',
    style({
      'display': 'none',
      opacity: 0,
    })
  ),
  state('show',
    style({
      'display': 'block',
      opacity: 1,
    })
  ),
  transition('close => open', animate('350ms ease-in')),
  transition('open => close', animate('200ms ease-out')),
]);
```

How can I use "arrow_left" click action from "sidenavlistcomponent" to "menu button" of "headercomponent"?

Comment: all this code in a MCE stackblitz would have made it a lot easier to help

Comment: I know but it has been customized for my UI

Comment: Simplify it, pinpoint your exact problem and try to replicate it on Stackblitz. Trying to pinpoint exactly what's wrong to replicate it will make it easier for you to understand how it works (or doesn't), and in some cases you'll be able to solve it while doing so.

Comment: I correct it.thanks alot